# Got Soap response of .asmx web-service,but cannot link the response to listview

Tags: android, json, parsing, soap

I am really new to android and I've got a task to parse the .asmx webservise**(which returns JSON**) and get it's content in listview. I check few examples from web but it's not working out for me.

**Here's my code :**

```
package com.Parsing.SOAPParsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetMyTest";

    private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetMyTest";

    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static final String URL = "http://www.beyyondcareers.com/webservice.asmx";

    TextView tv;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> testList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private String result;

    private JSONArray JSONArr;

    private static final String TAG_TEST_ID = "TestId";
    private static final String TAG_ORG_ID = "OrgId";
    private static final String TAG_TEST_TYPE = "TestType";
    private static final String TAG_TEST_NAME = "TestName";
    private static final String TAG_NO_OF_SECTION= "NoOfSection";
    private static final String TAG_TEST_TIME = "TestTime";
    private static final String TAG_TEST_SCORE = "TestScore";
    private static final String TAG_DIRECTION = "Direction";
    private static final String TAG_DISPLAY = "Display";
    private static final String TAG_CREATE_ON = "CreateOn";
    private static final String TAG_CREATED_BY = "CreatedBy";
    private static final String TAG_SHOW_CALCULATOR = "ShowCalculator";
    private static final String TAG_COURSE_ID = "CourseId";
    private static final String TAG_STANDARD_ID = "StandardId";
    private static final String TAG_SUBJECT_ID = "SubjectId";
    private static final String TAG_IS_CONCEPTE_BUILDER = "IsConceptBuilder";
    private static final String TAG_CATEGORY = "TestCategory";   
    private static final String TAG_TEST_TYPE_ONE = "testTyp";
    private static final String TAG_STUDENT_ID = "StudentId";
    private static final String TAG_REF_ID = "ReferenceId";
    private static final String TAG_REF_TYPE = "ReferenceType";
    private static final String TAG_GROUP_ID = "GroupId";    
    private static final String TAG_DATE_ALLOCATION = "DateOfAllocation";
    private static final String TAG_ATTENDED = "Attended";
    private static final String TAG_ATTENDED_ON = "AttendedOn";
    private static final String TAG_ATTENDED_NO_OF_TIME = "AttendedNoOfTime";
    private static final String TAG_STUDENT_TYPE = "StudentType";   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            request.addProperty("StudentId",10);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                result=response.toString();
                //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());
                //JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Test0");
                JSONArr = new JSONArray(result);

                for(int i = 0; i < JSONArr.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = JSONArr.getJSONObject(i);

                    String testid = c.getString(TAG_TEST_ID);
                    String orgid = c.getString(TAG_ORG_ID);
                    String testtype = c.getString(TAG_TEST_TYPE);
                    String testname = c.getString(TAG_TEST_NAME);
                    String noofsection = c.getString(TAG_NO_OF_SECTION);
                    String testtime = c.getString(TAG_TEST_TIME);
                    String testscore = c.getString(TAG_TEST_SCORE);
                    String direction = c.getString(TAG_DIRECTION);
                    String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
                    String createdon = c.getString(TAG_CREATE_ON);
                    String createdby = c.getString(TAG_CREATED_BY);
                    String showcalc = c.getString(TAG_SHOW_CALCULATOR);
                    String courseid = c.getString(TAG_COURSE_ID);
                    String standardid = c.getString(TAG_STANDARD_ID);
                    String subjectid = c.getString(TAG_SUBJECT_ID);
                    String isconceptbuilder = c.getString(TAG_IS_CONCEPTE_BUILDER);
                    String testcatag = c.getString(TAG_CATEGORY);
                    String testtyp = c.getString(TAG_TEST_TYPE_ONE);
                    String studendid = c.getString(TAG_STUDENT_ID);
                    String refid = c.getString(TAG_REF_ID);
                    String reftype = c.getString(TAG_REF_TYPE);
                    String groupid = c.getString(TAG_GROUP_ID);
                    String dateofallocation = c.getString(TAG_DATE_ALLOCATION);
                    String attended = c.getString(TAG_ATTENDED);
                    String attendedon = c.getString(TAG_ATTENDED_ON);
                    String attendednooftime = c.getString(TAG_ATTENDED_NO_OF_TIME);
                    String studenttype = c.getString(TAG_STUDENT_TYPE);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_TEST_ID, testid);
                    map.put(TAG_TEST_TYPE, testtype);
                    map.put(TAG_TEST_NAME, testname);

                    testList.add(map);
                }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tv.setText(e.getMessage());
        }

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, testList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { TAG_TEST_ID, TAG_TEST_TYPE, TAG_TEST_NAME }, new int[] {
                        R.id.testid, R.id.type, R.id.testname});

        setListAdapter(adapter);                
    }

}
```

With this code i am just getting the JSON File but now i want to parse it and get some of its fields stored in listview.

**My JSON output is like this:**

```
{
 "Test0": [
        5,              - TestId
        1,              - OrgId
        6,              - TestType
        "a",                - TestName
        1,              - NoOfSection
        5,              - TestTime
        1,              - TestScore
        "",             - Direction
        "Y",                - Display
        "\/Date(1316416540330)\/",  - CreatOn
        1,              - CreatedBy
        "N",                - ShowCalculator
        0,              - CourseId
        0,              - StandardId
        0,              - SubjectId
        "N",                - IsConecptBuilder
        "Word Test",            - TestCategory
        "Prospect Test",        - TestTyp
        19,             - StudentId
        5,              - ReferenceId
        "Test",             - ReferenceType
        0,              - GroupId
        "\/Date1332924520530)\/",   - DataOfAllocation
        "Y",                - Attended
        null,               - AttendedOn
        13,             - AttendedNoOfTime
        "Prospect"          - StudentType
      ]
}
```

can anyone please help me with modifying the code so i can populate the listview with 3 of the above fields.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Test0 is just aa JSONArray. You can access the items by id. Should be something like

```
JSONArray c = JSONArr.getJSONObject(i);
```

then acces the elements like

```
int TestId=0;
c.getString(TestId);
```

Comment: Just getting an exception as "Value 63 at 0 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONObject"                                    It would be great if u can integrate the code in my code,as i've very less knowledge with parsing. Sorry for trouble.

Comment: try changing JSONArr variable to type JSONObject